# Linux Installation

Tags: linux, boost

I am trying to install boost using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

But the installation is not successful and it gives the following error message

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
texlive-base
texlive-latex-base
texlive-latex-recommended
cm-super-minimal
cm-super
texlive-metapost
context
context-modules
texlive-font-utils
texlive-extra-utils
feynmf
latex-xcolor
pgf
latex-beamer
latex-cjk-common
texlive-xetex
latex-cjk-xcjk
latex-cjk-chinese
latex-cjk-japanese
latex-cjk-korean
thailatex
latex-fonts-thai-tlwg
latex-cjk-thai
latex-cjk-all
latex-sanskrit
latexmk
musixtex
texlive-generic-recommended
texlive-pstricks
prosper
texlive-bibtex-extra
texlive-fonts-extra
texlive-fonts-recommended
texlive-formats-extra
texlive-humanities
texlive-lang-swedish
texlive-lang-french
texlive-lang-tibetan
texlive-lang-czechslovak
texlive-games
texlive-lang-ukenglish
texlive-math-extra
texlive-generic-extra
texlive-latex3
texlive-lang-hebrew
texlive-lang-finnish
texlive-plain-extra
texlive-pictures
texlive-lang-polish
texlive-lang-cyrillic
texlive-lang-vietnamese
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone tell me the reason and how to resolve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: I imagine that `apt-get` had more output than that. Additionally, what does `sudo aptitude install libboost-all-dev` say? And have you run `sudo apt-get update` recently?

Comment: Yes i ran update command today. I don't have aptitude installed so it is giving command not found error in that case. When I tried to install aptitude it again gave me the above error

Comment: I still know that apt-get had more output than that. Generally speaking the first line of apt-get's output will be `Reading package lists... Done`.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a different solution? Compile your own boost! It doesn't take long and is pretty straightforward. Besides, depending on what linux distribution you are using, the repositories may not have the most recent version.

Here's a [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) that documents how to download and install boost.

To simplify that, all you need to do is

1. Download the tarball from http://www.boost.org/users/download/
2. Extract it:
   `tar xvjf boost_1_58_0.tar.bz2`
3. Go into the extracted directory:
   `cd boost_1_58_0`
4. Run `bootstrap`:
   `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/where/you/want/boost/installed`
5. Compile with `b2`:
   `./b2 install`
6. Profit